# exception connecting JSP and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am running JSP on Tomcat and MySQL through WAMP server. I am unable to connect the JSP to MySQL. Here is the code

```
<% 
try {
/* Create string of connection url within specified format with machine name, 
port number and database name. Here machine name id localhost and 
database name is usermaster. */ 
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"; 

// declare a connection by using Connection interface 
Connection connection = null; 

// Load JBBC driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 

/* Create a connection by using getConnection() method that takes parameters of 
string type connection url, user name and password to connect to database. */ 
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");

// check weather connection is established or not by isClosed() method 
if(!connection.isClosed())
%>
<% 
out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
connection.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){
%>
<%
out.println("Unable to connect to database."+ex.toString());
}
%>
```

I have even placed `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar` in `/lib` folder. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What's the error? And the root password is empty?

Comment: Please clean the code to a level that just has relevant code snippet. Paste the exception what you have got.

Comment: check if  you have  added port 3306 in your wamp cnf file

Comment: 3306 is default, you usually don't do anything

Comment: yep the root password is empty.....the exception which I got is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver...yeah satya...w8 leme chk

Comment: what is your lib folder? it's tomcat's lib folder, or WEB-INF/lib folder? or something else?

Comment: change this line Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); to Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); and try

Comment: yeah its tomcat 7...yeah lemme try this now.

Comment: the path where i have copied this connector file is C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\lib

Comment: Can you double check your mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar contains Java class files? I just download it from mysql site, it's called mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar, and your code works in my environment (tomcat 7).

Comment: You can open .jar file with winzip, winrar, or 7zip..., then you should see com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.class in it. If not, that would be the problem

Comment: yeah its there but i dont have a WEB-INF folder in my directory

Comment: can you unzip mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar file and see if it has Driver.class file in com/mysql/jdbc/ folder?

Comment: Yeah its present...M i required to add the path of the connector anywhere???

Comment: No, just restart Tomcat, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks You.It worked aftr reboot...!!!Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: through the discussion, it was determined that the class wasn't being found, because the server needed to be restarted.

It would really help if you could tell us what the exception actually is.

From what you've given, it could be a few things:

- Your jdbc resource isn't defined in your server.xml (or whatever other places it could be defined)
- Your connection is coming back null, but you're invoking a method on it.

I've never accessed resources this way, either.  Typically, I use a JNDI lookup with a DataSource from an InitialContext.

Comment: Also, make sure you have the mysql jdbc library installed on your server.

Comment: I am really sorry but I am a total newbie to these jargaon.The Exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Please can you guide me how to do all this.I am a total newbie to this language.

Comment: No need to apologize.  We've all been there.  What terms were confusing?

Comment: Ok, JNDI is a way of accessing resources by key-value pairs.  To use JNDI, you create (instantiate) an InitialContext object, lookup a JNDI resource, check its type, cast it to whatever you think it is, and use it.  Here is an example: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t138974-jndi-initialcontext-problem.html

Comment: Typically, you make that resource available by declaring it (writing it out) in some server config file.  Where and how you do that depends on what server you're using.

Comment: yeah sir so where should i declare this is my server.xml file..where can i find server.xml file

Comment: Judging from the exception you wrote down, either your server doesn't know your mysql-connector exists, you have the wrong class name or class path written down for it, or you haven't rebooted after adding the connector to the lib folder.

Comment: You should restart Tomcat after adding mysql jar file in the lib folder.

Comment: Sir I will learn JNDI now and will try doing it with that....Hopefully I will be here with questions on JNDI now...:)

Comment: Sir... If you have more questions about something else, you should make another post.

Comment: By the way, I'm glad I could help.  Also, if this way of accessing mysql works for you, I don't see why you should switch to jndi lookups.

Comment: Yeah Sir but I think that making  the same thing work using different ways is always better.Also is JNDI useful in other ways too????

Comment: You're right, JNDI is very useful.  If you want to redo this for the sake of learning a more standard way, then that's a great reason.  However, I like to stick with one way of doing things within one application.  It makes it a heck of a lot easier for other people (and for you) to read your code, because they only have to understand one mechanism instead of many.

Comment: Yeah Sir,So I will learn JNDI but ll employ your approach to use onli one thing for an application.Thank You Once again Sir,Have a nic time and good luck for your future,

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar` file into `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp `context`.

Folder structure of Java EE web app must be:

```
/webapp   <--- This is known as `context` folder
|
|-------/WEB-INF
|       |
|       |-----------/classes
|       | 
|       |-----------/lib
|                    mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar
| sample.jsp
```

To request the sample.jsp,

```
http://localhost:here_is_port_number/webapp/sample.jsp
```

I'd suggest your to create your web-app in tomcat [auto deploy folder - C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\webapps\](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html) .

Comment: Sir but where can I find my WEB-INF/lib....I have my folder as C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\lib where i have copied this.Please guide me as I am new to this thing

Comment: Sir I have it in another directory.So should I copy the same in my directory and what editing I am required to do then?

Comment: Leaving it in tomcat's lib folder is perfectly fine. You won't be able to setup JNDI if you only put it in WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: yeah its there only...c:\C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\webapps\nil\mysqls.jsp

Comment: Yeah Sir I ll auto deploy it now..Thank You